how can i set object and array to state at the same time
there is not a problem with data coming from server;
when the code activates, i get a problem 'arr[0] is not iterable'.
This is object data {a24cx1bs3yov2: {...},b64cx1bs3yo21: {...},c34cx1bs3yoh2: {...}}
This is array data [0: {...}]
useEffect(() => {
    let arr = [];
    try{
      const getChats = () => {
      const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid), (doc) => {
        if(doc.data()){
         // this one pushes object
          arr.push(doc.data());
        }
      });

      const fetch = onSnapshot(doc(db, "userGroups", currentUser.uid), (doc) => {
        if(doc.data()){
          // this one pushes array
          arr.push(doc.data().groups);
        }
      });

      setChats([...arr[0],...arr[1])

      return () => {
        fetch()
        unsub();
      };
    };
    
    currentUser.uid && getChats();
  }catch(err){console.log(err);}
  }, [currentUser.uid]);


[0: {...}] arrays are not key-value pairs like objects, so make sure to edit your question with the mock data you are retrieving. what does onSnapshot do? because you are using async without await and that may be the problem.

@MHDAlaaAlhaj, that is not the problem. See answer below. The OP does include mock data. Object format and Array format.

From your above mention, doc.data() in const unsub = onSnapshot is an Object. You cannot spread an Object into an Array. This operation is the culprit:
setChats([...arr[0], ...arr[1]])
Since you already have the Objects in the Array —arr— and you know their indices, simply extract them and placed them into the Array that will be set as the new state. You don’t need a spread operation.
setChats(arr.slice(0, 2))
